# How can I update my Nikon B700 firmware?

Tags: nikon

I have just bought a second hand Nikon b700 and it has never had a firmware update. I have tried several times and could not get the camera to see the firmware update file on the memory card.
Having looked on lots of places it seems to be a problem to lots of us. Am I missing something?

#### Steps I followed

1. I have downloaded the update file to my laptop.
2. I have formatted the card in the camera.
3. I have transferred it to the card I am not sure if this part is done in the right way.
4. I put the card back in to the camera, switched it on and gone into the firmware menu. The new firmware is not visible it only shows the original 1.1 firmware.

The battery is fully charged as this is said to important. Can anyone help please?

Comment: There are step-by-step instructions here: [https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/303.html](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/303.html). Have you completed each step _exactly_ as instructed? If you are unsure about any particular step, say so.

Comment: Hi Roly and welcome to Photo.SE! As osullic says it is indeed important to indicate if/how you've followed the steps of the instruction and what the outcome of each step was. You can [rewrite your question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/124898/edit) using the edit button to include the 8 steps provided by Nikon and indicate the outcome of each step (if necessary with a screenshot).

Comment: What firmware is on the camera, and what firmware are you trying to update to?

Answer (score 0):

> I have transferred it to the card I am not sure if this part is done in the right way.

If you don't know what you did, how are we supposed to know in order to help you?

In general, firmware update files should be decompressed (*i.e.* unzipped or extracted) on the computer before transferring them to the memory card. When placed on the memory card they should be in the card's *root directory*. That is, if your memory card is drive M on your computer, then you should place the extracted firmware file at M:\ *firmware file name*.bin. If you place it inside an existing folder, such as M:\DCIM\ *firmware file name*.bin it will not work.

Have you followed the [instructions for the B700](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/303.html) at Nikon's Download Center?

Comment: Right lets see if I can explain what I am doing. I have down loaded the file this has a little box with an arrow on it which looks like it has books or files in it F-B700-V15W I have used 7-Zip to extract files I how have another folder B700Update I have copied this to the card put it back into the camera gone it to menu to firmware version and it still shows only Ver.1.0 what am I doing wrong. I have just put the card back into the laptop and opened it it has 3 files in it top one is B700Update,  then DCIM, then NCFL,

Comment: @Roly Don't copy the "B700Update"  folder onto the card. Copy only the **file** inside that folder with the file extension *.bin* directly to the root directory of the card. If that file is inside another folder on the card your camera will not see it. If you're not seeing file extensions with your computer's setup, view each file's properties to find the *.bin* file. If you're not seeing a *.bin* file, then ***follow the instructions on the Nikon page*** to extract it by running the **F-B700-V15W.exe** file you downloaded instead of using a zip file utility.